# How to detect a child node that contains a specific class in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this renderization done by reactJS

render() {

```
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div className="wrapper2">
            <nav id="menu-principal" className="main menu-principal">
              <ul>
                <li><NavLink className="home-link" exact to="/">início</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink exact to="/nota_biografica">nota biográfica</NavLink></li>

              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div className="page-content">
              <Route exact path='/nota_biografica' render={() => <NotaBiografica />} />                  
              <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

When I click on the link that contains a "home-link" class, I would like to do some action. Like an action I tried to do in the example below which didn't work. How can I solve it? Thank you.

```
var el = document.querySelector(".menu-principal");
      el.onclick = (event) => {                 
        for(var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
          if(el.childNodes[i].className === "home-link"){
            alert('true')
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: What is this "some action" you want to do? Also, `NavLink` is part of your router and it already performs an action when you click it. (Causing a different `Route` to be rendered)

Comment: It doesn't matter yet. I didn't build a function yet that it will be trigger in the future. For a while I want only alert ''true" if the child node has a "home-link" class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the element you targeted is `<NavLink>` tag which normally should navigate to another router page, I believe the event you have attached will not get running. I suggest you to not using `<NavLink>` just use `this.props.history.push('/path/to/route')` instead on the `onClick` handler ( after the procedures you need to run before navigating to another routing address ).

On the following example, Please pay attention about `withRouter` and i change `<NavLink>` to span then attach `onHomeCLick` handler to it:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withRouter, Route, BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
class YourComponent extends Component {

  onHomeCLick = () => {
    //DO something here prior to router navigation of ".home-link" element

    this.props.history.push( '/' );
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div className="wrapper2">
            <nav id="menu-principal" className="main menu-principal">
              <ul>
                <li><span className="home-link" onClick={this.onHomeCLick}>início</span></li>
                <li><NavLink exact to="/nota_biografica">nota biográfica</NavLink></li>

              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div className="page-content">
              <Route exact path='/nota_biografica' render={() => <NotaBiografica />} />
              <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default withRouter( YourComponent );
```

**UPDATE===========**

Another trick if you like to use `<NavLink>`, the only solution is a "Call back" way. It will trigger once you navigated to the route ( I still can't see if there is way to do it prior to navigation ). Here we go:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";

class YourComponent extends Component {

  isActive= (match, location) => {
    if (match) {
      console.log('Hi i am active, do something here');
    }
    return match;
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div className="wrapper2">
            <nav id="menu-principal" className="main menu-principal">
              <ul>
                <li><NavLink className="home-link" activeClassName="active" isActive={this.isActive}>início</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink exact to="/nota_biografica">nota biográfica</NavLink></li>

              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div className="page-content">
              <Route exact path='/nota_biografica' render={() => <NotaBiografica />} />
              <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it mandatory? Stop to use 'NavLink' for my app work by using Ref?

Comment: I update my answer to not using Ref and give you example of how to using it, you can just using Handler and use the power of `withRouter` to get `this.props.history.push('/router/path')`.

Comment: But I like to use "activeClassName" from "NavLink". Does it works on 'withRouter'? or does exist there another one similar?

Comment: Hum, well I am not sure if there is a real solution for it. Since React is working with "Synthetic" event which means we can't easily do something like `event.preventDefault()` or something like that to handle `<NavLink>` manually. I will update my answer with another trick, if it may fit with your `<NavLink>` necessity.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking forward to your answer

Comment: Actually you can also using `withRouter` way, but it will involve manual check whether `this.props.location.pathname` is match to expected router path for example : `let isHomeActiveCss= this.props.location.pathname === '/' ? 'active' : ''`. Then do : `<span className={isHomeActiveCss}> início </span>`

Comment: I have updated my answer with `<NavLink>` "Callback way" solution :)